# MaxQDA keeps making a word cloud that only consists of numbers

Tags: code-generation, word-cloud

I'm new to maxQDA, and for some reason, whenever I try to generate a word cloud, it only puts in numbers and hyphenated words. I didn't change anything from when I previously generated a word cloud (that worked). [Word cloud that only includes numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amhpa.png)

I haven't filtered for numbers or anything. I haven't changed any of the settings. My version of maxQDA doesn't allow me to choose a setting to exclude numbers. My documents group consists of around 1900 paragraph-style answers to a survey, but the word cloud only includes the numbers from those answers, instead of the words. Is there anything I can do to fix this?